# Mysql - How can I select rows by year if I have only the timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table

```
Id      Timestamp
1    |  1302566399
2    |  1502745635
3    |  1374679999
4    |  1264575886
5    |  1154645755
```

How can I select only the rows where the year is 2011 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp, '%Y') = 2011;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE YEAR(`timestamp`) = 2011
```

Comment: If you apply year() function to a unix_timestamp it returns null

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way has been already suggested in rest of answers (directly from query)

You can do it this way too

```
$year_start = strtotime('2011-01-01');
$year_end = strtotime('2011-12-31 23:59:59.000');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM your_table 
        WHERE Timestamp>=$year_start AND Timestamp<=$year_end";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
```

function [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) depends of time zone set.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table where from_unixtime(field,'%Y') = 2011
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a query like this, where myTimestamp is the column with the timestamp in it

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(myTimestamp, '%Y') = '2011'
```