# Make an sql select statement filter through year

Tags: mysql

I have an sql select statement like this:

```
select * from orders where user_id = '1578' and delivery_fee = '2000'
```

I want to only take dates of this year (2017), I have a variable called "created_at" it has variables like this for example

```
2017-02-0312:00:00

select * from orders where user_id = '1578' and delivery_fee = '2000' and created_at LIKE 'date(Y)%'
```

but its not working, can anyone help?

Comment: have you used datetime or varchars as a data type of created_at?

Comment: yes i did before but it wouldnt work @SahilManchanda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please tryt this:

```
    SELECT * FROM orders WHERE user_id = '1578' AND delivery_fee = '2000' AND YEAR(`created_at`) = 2017
```

Idea and resource to see : [Mysql - How can I select rows by year if I have only the timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676790/mysql-how-can-i-select-rows-by-year-if-i-have-only-the-timestamp#answer-5676836)

---

### UPDATE

I am assuming that created_at is TIMESSTAMP or DATETIME

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE user_id = '1578' AND delivery_fee = '2000' AND DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y') = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

For reference see conversation here : [sql get result of current year only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745475/sql-get-result-of-current-year-only)

Comment: can i not put 2017? so i dont have to end up changing it every year? Thats why I wanted to put "Y"

Answer (score 1):

You can make it like this :

```
select * from orders where user_id = '1578' and delivery_fee = '2000' and created_at > '2017-01-01 21:00:00'
```

will return orders for user 1578 and and delivery_fee = 2000 where the order was created after 2017

Comment: I want the year to be dynamic, to always capture this year

Comment: easy, you can use concatenation, `' ... delivery_fee = '2000' and created_at > " + $year +"-01-01 21:00:00 ...'`